# How to query for a count within a count (without using a sub query)?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, mysql-5.5

If you study this table for a moment, you will see **Dave** is unique because he has won `multiple awards in a single year` and he has done this `for multiple years`.

```
person  award   year
-------------------------------
Dave    red     2015
Dave    blue    2015
Dave    red     2013
Dave    green   2013
Susan   blue    2015
Susan   green   2011
Susan   red     2011
Susan   red     2010
Tom     red     2012
Tom     blue    2012
Tom     green   2012
Tom     yellow  2012
Tom     purple  2012
```

**Is there a way to query for Dave (multi-award winner for more than 1 year) without using a subquery?** 
For example, you could say `GROUP BY person HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) > 1 AND COUNT(*) > 3` but this would also yield Susan.

Comment: Why do you have a restriction on the use of a subquery?

Comment: Right after I posted this question, I realized a sub-query will be fine. But the question still remains? Is there a simple way to achieve this? I'm thinking not...

Comment: @DavidGraham -- you should edit your question not limiting the subquery... I posted a solution using one - not sure it would be possible without.

Comment: If there is a way to do it without a subquery it definitely wouldn't be a simpler way.

Comment: Agreed - without a subquery it gets very complicated, if it is even possible.

Comment: Yeah, I end up hitting several of these situations and always go for the sub-query, which breaks the consistent way I prefer to name/alias the fields I `SELECT` (ie. `people.awards`,`awards.color`) since I need the tables inner-joined and have to pass the select to the outer query.I was looking to see if there was solution without sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use this:

```
select a1.person
  from awards a1
  join awards a2
    on a1.person = a2.person
   and a1.year = a2.year
   and a1.award <> a2.award
 group by a1.person
having count(distinct a1.year) > 1
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b98bf/8/0

But you would be better off with a subquery:

```
select person
  from (select person, year, count(*) as num_in_yr
          from awards
         group by person, year) x
 group by person
having sum(num_in_yr >= 2) >= 2
```

**Fiddle:** 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b98bf/7/0

Comment: Ah, I see what you did here...using the additional `JOIN` so that every person-year must have a "pair" (then `distinct` out the duplicate years) and count. Clever! And as you mention, I should probably just stick to a sub-query (which I use all the time, but now I'm confirmed there's not much of a different solution). Thanks!

Comment: Definitely a very clever solution.